# uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngcordova

I am using ngcordova sqllite plugin in ionic framework.
This is the html part

```
<ion-content padding="true" class="has-header" ng-controller="qtnController">
   <div class="list list-inset">
     <label class="item item-input">
      <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
      <input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchQuestion">
     </label>
   </div>
   <div class="card" ng-repeat="i in reta track by i.id">
      <div class="item item-divider">{{i.name | uppercase}}</div>
      <div class="item item-text-wrap">Description : {{i.description}}</div>
      <div class="item item-divider">Id : {{i.id}}</div>
   </div>
```

Here is js part :-

```
modules.controller("qtnController", function($scope,$cordovaSQLite){
   $scope.reta = [];
   var query = "select id,name,questions,options,description from questionSet order by id desc";
   db.transaction(function(){
     $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,query).then(function(res){
       if(res.rows.length > 0){
         $scope.reta = res.rows;
       }else{console.log("No results found");}
     });
   });
})
```

This all works fine but getting this error

```
uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

And putting the filter in ng-repeat like this produce error.

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="i in reta track by i.id | repeat : searchQuestion">
```

Comment: What does your `repeat` filter look like?

Comment: repeat filter is a normal search string